# call async asihttp in different view controller

Tags: iphone

I try to use UINavigationController to navigate from one view controller to another.
In both viewController , the viewWillAppear

I call asihttp using async mode.

but this always cause the app crash.

I try to use the function of asihttp '[request cancel]'
in the wiewWillDisaaoear, but the error still exist

Welcome any comment

Comment: Can you Please post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Following code in my app and i also did forth-back using UINavigationController but it didn't give me any crash. I suggest you  to show your code here so it will help you a lot to find out your resolution.

Here, I am showing you my code..see if it will help you.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation  duration:1];   
NSURL *urlf = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your url"];
ASIHTTPRequest *requestdiff = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:urlf];
[requestdiff setDelegate:self];
[requestdiff release];
[self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation  duration:1];    
}
```